# Android 4.0 custom notification like google music

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to create a custom notification with a progress bar and a delete button.

Screenshot:

[image]

I succeed to create a custom notification with a progress bar, but I did not manage to create the delete event. I want to cancel the notification and stop the upload once the user click on the "x" (as in google music, so i don't want to start an activity to clear the notification).

Here is my working code :

```
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);    


    CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
    CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, UploadEventsReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.upload_progress);
    notification.contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.text, contentIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(this.notificationId, notification);
```

At the line

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, UploadEventsReceiver.class);
```

I tried with a BroadCast receiver without "broadcasting" but I don't know if it's the right way to do it and I didn't succeed to make it work. What should I use and how to use it ?

Comment: Nice, I was about to implement what I just found in your screenshot: neat hardware control toggles, e.g. for WiFi, rotation, or flight mode. Are you running a custom ROM or did you find that on the Market? Thanks for your help and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how it's made in google music, but you can set onClickListener for any view in layout that passed to `RemoteViews`. Just do like this:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(widgetPackage, R.layout.widget);
Intent action = new Intent(context, Your_cancel_broadcast.class);
action.setAction(CANCEL_BROADCAST_ACTION);
actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, action, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.your_x_btn, actionPendingIntent);
```

and create broadcast, that receives `CANCEL_BROADCAST_ACTION` and stops what you want, and cancel this notification.

Comment: Will the intent be broadcasted ? Or will the intend be only send to my cancel_broadcast ?

Comment: It depends on value of `CANCEL_BROADCAST_ACTION` - if it is custom(smth like "lalala") - only your broadcast will receive this intent

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think (according to the documentation) that your method is deprecated.

You should use sth like:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
builder.setContentTitle("Your notification title");
builder.setContentText("Your notification text");
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_your_icon);
builder.setContentIntent(yourIntent);
notificationManager.notify(null, YOUR_UNIQUE_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.getNotification());
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

Comment: Note: Notification.Builder is available only in API 11+.  The v4 support library has NotificationBuilderCompat, but according to the following link it is currently missing its setProgress method. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30755 i