# Buttons Action on Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to add buttons to my own custom notification.

However, RemoteViews' `setOnClickPendingIntent()` is not working.

I saw PowerAMP has similar functions, which is just what I want.

[image]

Does anybody know how PowerAMP achieves this?

Comment: what is the error.. show some code and the error logs...

Comment: I followed this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711966/android-4-0-custom-notification-like-google-music
but it did'nt work, my buttons didn't respond to my click...

Comment: Make sure that the activities or receivers you're trying to trigger with your PendingIntents are published in AndroidManifest.xml. The SystemUI can't see inside your APK otherwise.